# How can i check if a firebase realtime database value exists already? (FLUTTER/DART)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

`

Expanded(

```
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: taskRef != null ? taskRef!.onValue : null,
            builder: (context,  snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError && data1!="null"){

              final snapshot2 = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                  ((snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value??{}) as Map);

              if(snapshot2 == null){
                return Center(child: Text("No tasks added yet", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    fontSize: 18),),);
              }else{
                Map<String, dynamic> map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot2);

                var tasks = <Task>[];
                for(var taskMap in map.values){
                  Task task = Task.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(taskMap));
                  tasks.add(task);
                }

                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: tasks.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){

                    Task task1 = tasks[index];

                    return Container`
```

[image: task info]
This is a part of my realtime firebase database...for only one user in this photo.
[image: figure1]

The code that i used to show the tasks in my app. Should i do the same thing for my problem? The db has `userId -> day -> taskId -> informations`. When I insert in my DB a new Task (all the information) I want to check first if the `startTime` already exists. How is this possible? It confuses me because of the random `taskId` child.
taskRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(uid).child("images").child("MONDAY");

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you already tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please also [edit] your question and add the `User Tasks` collection structure. For example, are `images` and `taskID` an array or a map?